# How can I make code execution wait with async await?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

I have an init function which I wrote in a ridiculous way just to examine async/await:

```
function init() {
    console.log(1)
    accountsStore.getAccounts().then(() => {
        categoriesStore.getCategories().then(() => {
            sheetItemStore.getSheetItems().then(() => {
                accountsStore.getTotal().then(() => {
                    sheetItemStore.getTotals().then(() => {
                        balanceStore.getGrandTotal().then(() => {
                            console.log(8)
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    })
    console.log(9)
}
```

All functions take the following shape:

```
async function getAccounts() {
    let response = await axios.get(route('accounts.index', {'id': baseStore.balance.id}))
    accounts.value = response.data
    console.log(2)
}
```

What I want is for all functions to have completed before I render the view but the console gives me 1,9,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. Is there a way to wait for the functions in init to complete before the code continues?

Comment: You shouldn't nest .then, this is an antipattern. You need to continue the execution where console.log(8) is, that's what async/await does. It is syntax sugar, it doesn't improve the understanding of promises. You may have a similar problem in a place where init is called. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call , a general problem with possible solutions including async-await

Comment: I only nested them to see what would happen i never intended to keep it like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `init()` function into an `async` function. Now you can `await` for each function to complete.

```js
async function init() {
    console.log(1);
    await accountsStore.getAccounts();
    await categoriesStore.getCategories();
    await sheetItemStore.getSheetItems();
    await accountsStore.getTotal();
    await sheetItemStore.getTotals();
    await balanceStore.getGrandTotal();
    console.log(8);
    console.log(9);
}
```

You also need to await the `init()` function if something depends on its exection. Here I'm using an IIFE but you can do however you want.

```js
(async () => {
    await init();

    // Rest of your code.
})();
```

Comment: i ended up taking a more subtle approach only awaiting for the data that was specifly needed for the view in question. That solved the issue. "await balanceStore.getGrandTotal()"

Answer (score 2):

You can use `async/await` in your example like this:

```
 async function init() {
        console.log(1);
            await accountsStore.getAccounts();
            await categoriesStore.getCategories();
            await sheetItemStore.getSheetItems();
            await accountsStore.getTotal();
            await sheetItemStore.getTotals();
            await balanceStore.getGrandTotal();
        console.log(9);
    }
```